# After successful merge changes not appearing in code base

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0JGp.jpg)Hoping to find someone well versed in SVN to assist with a problem that has baffled both me and a colleague well experienced in SVN.

I recently was merging in new content to Trunk. I saw in the dialog box the files I'd edited all scroll down the screen as normal, and then received the 'Merge successful' message.

However, when I looked in Trunk none of the changes were present. In repo browser where you typically can see the author username of the most recent changes as well as the time stamp, it showed a previous merge not made by me.

Baffled, my colleague came to observe the whole process and confirmed that he was seeing the same thing: the merge appearing to succeed, but none of the updates persisting.

Has anyone seen this before, and could anyone offer any advice? I've spent a few hours googling at this point and am exhausting likely culprits.

Comment: You're sure you're not doing a [record-only merge](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html#svn.branchmerge.advanced.blockchanges), right? I know you'd have to go out of your way to do it but it's worth asking...

Comment: Also, you say you do the merge, then look in the repo browser and don't see the changes.  You know you need to commit your changes after merging before they show up in the repository, right?

Comment: Yes, naturally I commit - I'm a little new to it but not quite that green :)

Comment: Just making sure.  Did you see the changes in your working copy before you committed? And the commit succeeds? What revision number is it? Do you not see your commit at all in the repo browser?  Are you sure you're committing to the same place you're looking at in the repo browser?  Dumb questions, I know, but chances are better they're the issue rather than finding a critical bug in Subversion.

Comment: Yup, all good questions, not dumb at all - so at this point  we were on revision 69600. The commit does succeed, and in the repo browser you don't see the correct timestamp, which is what alerted us to the fact that this is happening. Because a more senior admin watched each step of the checking process, almost exactly as you mention, we were sure it was the right destination/right merge-commit process/etc.

Comment: Added an image although it sounds like you are familiar enough to envision what I'm saying...just to be safe

Answer (score 0):

You won't see merged changes in the repo browser until you commit those changes:
A merge only changes the files in your working copy, not directly in the repository.

Which means you have to first commit your changes.

Comment: Sorry, that was implied. The trunk was committed after merging, of course.